# Proving that $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ is not integrable both on $B^2 - \vec 0$, and $\mathbb{R}^2 - \bar B^2$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 151, question 3, it is asked that

> Let $U$ be the open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of all $x$ with $\|x\|<1$.  Let
>   $$ f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} $$
>   for $(x,y) \ne 0$.  Determine whether $f$ is integrable over $U\setminus 0$ and over $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \overline{U}$; if so, evaluate.

I have given the following answers, but, as you can see below, in both cases I have found that the integral does not exists, so is everything correct in my answers, because the author says "if so evaluate", which means in general at least one of the integral exists and we are going to evaluate it :).

**My answers:**

Let $g(r,\theta) = (r \cos\theta, r \sin \theta),$
where $g: (0,1)\times (0,2\pi) \to U - \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^x | y = 0, x \geq 0\}.$
Note that the excluded set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^x | y = 0, x \geq 0\}$ is of measure zero, hence it does not contribute the integral that we are going to evaluate.

**For $U - \vec 0,$** let $C_n = [1/n, 1-1/n] \times [1/n, 2\pi - 1/n]$ be a rectifiable set in $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$ s.t $C_n \subset Int (C_{n+1}) $ and their union is $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$. Since for each $n \geq 2$, this set is a rectifiable set s.t $n+1$-th set contains $n$-th one and the union of these sets form a cover for $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$, we can evaluate the improper integral of any function over $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$ by first integrating it on $C_n$, and then taking the limit as $n \to \infty$.

Now, by Fubini's theorem, we have 
$$\int_{1/n}^{2\pi - 1/n} \int_{1/n}^{1-1/n} \frac{1}{r^2} * |r| = ln(\frac{1 - 1/n}{1/n} ) * (2\pi - 2/n),$$
but this function blows up as $n\to \infty$, hence it is not bounded, hence the improper integral does not exists.

**For $\mathbb{R}^n - \bar U$,** we form the partition 
$$[1+ 1/n, n] \times [1/n, 2\pi - 1/n],$$
for $n\geq 2$, and apply the same reasoning, and get 
$$ln(\frac{n}{1 + 1/n} ) * (2\pi - 2/n),$$
but this also blows up as $n \to \infty$, hence it is not bounded, hence the integral does not exists.

---

**Question:**

Is there anything wrong with the answers given above ? Is there any flaw ?

Comment: @Surb Yes, I know from Calculus courses, but the thing is I cannot find the error in my above argument, either.

Comment: @Surb No, I do not have such an "idea", why do you think that I think like that ?

Comment: I just saw "hence it's not bounded when $n\to \infty$", so I thought you were thinking that... Ok I'll read your proof...

Comment: It's complicate to understand what you want to do. Moreover $C_n$ is not a partition of $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$. For example $ C_1\cap C_2\neq \emptyset$, so they are not disjunct.

Comment: @Surb I use the wrong term: I was looking for a rectifiable sets $C_n$ s.t $C_n \subset C_{n+1}$ and their union is $(0,1) \times $0,2\pi$.

Comment: Your definition of $g$ is weird… you define $$g(r,\theta, \phi) = (r \sin\phi \cos\theta, r \sin\phi \sin \theta, r cos\phi)$$ and then claim $$g: (0,1)\times (0,2\pi) \to U - \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^x | y = 0, x \geq 0\}$$ But obviously $g$ depends of $3$ parameters and has a value out of $\Bbb R^3$ so neither your definition area nor your image is suitable.

Comment: @Gono I just mixed the spherical with cylindrical case, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: "in both cases I have found that the integral does not exists, so is everything correct in my answers, because the author says "if so evaluate", which means in general at least one of the integral exists and we are going to evaluate it" No this does not mean that. Yes the integral diverges both at zero and at infinity.

Comment: @Did Yes, I know English, and I do know that it does not mean that, but the very fact that that statement is there persuade me to question the validity of my answer,   hence my question. I mean as far the question concerns, that sentence is not related to the it, so you can just ignore it.

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote ?

Comment: "so you can just ignore it." Hmmm... but your whole question revolves around this sentence.

Comment: @Did Oh, really. How so ?

Comment: @Did If that is the case, if I just copy-paste the whole question, and just delete that sentence and ask a new question like that, will I get a different answers ? I really curious how that sentence changes the math that we are doing in here ?

Comment: Sorry but you seem too much interested in wordplays and rhetorics, rather than addressing the mathematical points raised about your question, for my present mood. No big deal.

Answer (score 5):

> Since for each $n\ge 2$, this set is a rectifiable set s.t $n+1$-th set contains $n-th$ one and the union of these sets form a cover for $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$, we can evaluate the improper integral of any function over $(0,1)\times (0,2\pi)$ by first integrating it on $C_n$, and then taking the limit as $n \to \infty$

This is wrong...
e.g. take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and the domain $C = (-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ then 
$f$ is not integrable over $C$ because $$\int_C \, |f(x)| \, dx = \infty$$ but by your "assumption" it would hold with $$C_n = (-1,1)\setminus\left(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ that:

$$\int_D\; f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{C_n} f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$$ because $$ \int_{C_n} f(x) \, dx = 0$$ for all $n\ge 1$

Comment: Just for the positive values: you have $[1/n, 1-1/n]$, but $\int_{1/n}^{1-1/n} 1/n  = ln(\frac{1-1/n}{1/n } ) = ln(n-1) $, and this blows up as $\to \infty$ ? Your computations are hidden from us, I cannot understand how do you compute that value ?

Comment: No you have $$\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right)$$ and so you get $$\int_\frac{1}{n}^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = -\ln\frac{1}{n} = \ln(n)$$ and yes, this tends to infinity as $n \to \infty$, that's why $$\int_C \, |f(x)| \, dx = \infty$$ holds. But on the other hand you have $$\int_{C_n} f(x) \, dx = \int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x} dx + \int_\frac{1}{n}^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = -\ln(n) + \ln(n) = 0$$

Comment: I'm still confused: $\int_{-1}^{-1/n} 1/x = [ln|x| ]|_{-1}^{-1/n} = ln(1/n) - 0 \to - \infty,$, but we have also $ln(n)$, so $ln(1/n) + ln(n) = l(1) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yeah… that's why $f$ is not integrable on $C$ but on each $C_n$ with integral value $0$.

Comment: Ok, let me correct one thing: We are integrating $|f|$, so we should take the integral $\int_{-1}^{-1/n} -1/x$, but this leads $[ln(|1/x|)]_{-1}^{-1/n} = ln(n) - 0 \to \infty$ as $n\to \infty.$

Comment: If you are integrating |f| you are right… that's why you have $$\int_C |f(x)| dx = \infty$$

Comment: Ok, after reading the question again, and the theorem that in on the book of Munkres, I'm really confused, and did all the computation that I have done above, again.For example,

Comment: $\int_{C_n} |1/x|  = \int_{B_n} -1/x + \int_{D_n} 1/x$, where $B_n = (-1, -1/n)$ and $D_n = (1, 1/n).$ Hence, $$ln(|1/x|)|_{-1}^{-1/n} + ln(|x|)|_{1/n}^1 = ln(|-n|) - ln(|-1|) + ln(|1|) - ln(|1/n|) = ln(n) - ln(1/n) = ln(n^2) \to \infty$$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes… that's fine… why are you confused? This proves that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable over $C$ hence $$\int_C \frac{1}{x} dx$$ is not well defined. Now integrate $\frac{1}{x}$ instead of $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|$ with your way. What is your result?

Comment: But the theorem only works for non-negative functions, so we cannot use it with $1/x$, and we do not have to because as long as we can find a sequence of $C_n$s s.t $\int_C |1/x|$ is bounded, we can conclude that $\int_C 1/x$ exists.

Comment: Similarly, if we can find a sequence of $C_n$ s.t $\int |1/x|$ is unbounded, we can conclude that $\int 1/x$ does not exists.

Comment: > "But the theorem only works for non-negative functions".
This is not what you claimed before… changing assumptions after a bunch if comments is not very useful. For non-negative functions this is not a "theorem" it's nothing else then monotone convergence.